# Can you draw on cursors in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cursors

I wanted to draw on cursors or atleast open and create cursor files (preferably .CUR), here's what I tried:

```py
from PIL import Image

curImg = Image.new("RGBA", (32,) * 2, (0, 0, 0, 0))
curImg.save("test.cur", format="CUR")
```

Comment: Pillow doesn't [support](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#read-only-formats) writing CUR files, only reading them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, so the comments all say that I can't edit cursors with *only* PIL, so with my beeg brain, I published a module called `pycur`!

`pycur` is a module that aims to draw on cursors as easy as possible with no modules!

[Help me](https://pycur.glitch.me) in my mission for `pycur`! You'll be thanked!

Comment: While I commend you for solving the problem yourself, there’s currently not much here in the answer besides a proposed name. The link doesn’t go to anything useful at the moment, so this isn’t an answer to the question…!?

Comment: @deceze I'll build the website soon, I'm already coding an editor so that community can participate and a forum after that! ;)

Comment: Seems like a lot more work than just coding the library and throwing it up on GitHub…!?